# Selenium returns empty values

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath, data-science

Can you help me to solve the follow issue?
I'm creating a function with Selenium to scrape some jobs from Glassdor, but even though I'm using the correct XPath to get the "salary estimate" it just returns the `except` results.

```
xpath = './/span[@class="css-18034rf e1wijj242"]' 

try:
    salary_estimate.append(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath).text)

except:
    salary_estimate.append("#N/A")
    pass
```

Here is the salary estimate on the job card and the search [link](https://www.glassdoor.co.in/Job/united-states-data-engineer-jobs-SRCH_IL.0,13_IN1_KO14,27.htm?suggestCount=0&suggestChosen=false&clickSource=searchBtn&typedKeyword=Data%2520Engineer&typedLocation=United%2520States&context=Jobs&dropdown=0):

[salary estimate position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHFZu.png)

Comment: This violates Glassdoor's [terms of use](https://www.glassdoor.com/about/terms/). Please abide by their wishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That because the locator you are using is dynamically generated and changes on every reload and will not return anything

Try using this

```
//span[@data-test='detailSalary']
```

This will return you all ranges and when you do a .text you will get output as `$74T - $1L (Glassdoor Est.)`

Then to further Filter out the Salary ranges if you want , you have to extract just the parent text element

```
 parent_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//span[@data-test='detailSalary']");
 print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].childNodes[0].textContent;', parent_element).strip())
```

This will give output as `$55.00 - $85.00 Per hour`

Similarly you can extract all by iterating through the list of elements

```
parent_list = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//span[@data-test='detailSalary']");


for el in parent_list:
  
   print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].childNodes[0].textContent;', el).strip());
```